# Is "wäre ... können" used for "sein" verbs?

Tags: auxiliary-verb, sein-or-haben

Take the following sentence:

> Ich hätte Cricket spielen können.

meaning

> I could have played cricket.

*spielen* has *haben* as an auxiliary, and it is obvious that *hätte können* is the right way to use it.

However, with verbs that take *sein* as an auxiliary, which of these is correct?

> Ich **wäre** in die Stadt gehen sollen.

**or**

> Ich **hätte** in die Stadt gehen sollen.

They are both intending to mean

> I should have gone into town.

Comment: "and it is obvious that hätte können is the right way to use it." - Actually, it isn't so obvious because something interesting happens here: The regular past participle in *hätte gekonnt* is replaced by an infinitive, resulting in *hätte können*. This construction is called *Ersatzinfinitiv*. Just for completeness. :-)

Comment: @Chris - I more meant that it is obvious that "hätte" is the right auxiliary to use

Comment: Ah, now I understand your reasoning: Both *spielen* and *können* take *haben* as auxiliary, so it mustn't be *wäre* but *hätte*. Okay. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct version is

> Ich **hätte** in die Stadt gehen sollen.

Let's leave out the middle part for a moment; then the phrase becomes

> Ich **hätte** gesollt.

The auxiliary is *haben* because the modal verb *sollen* demands *haben*, not *sein*. If we reinsert the middle part, which is an infinitive construction, then the past participle *gesollt* is replaced by the infinitive *sollen* (*Ersatzinfinitiv*).

**Recipe:**
As we can see, the difficult part of the sentence is that it has two infinitives. How do we determine which auxiliary is needed? We must find out which of the two infinitives determines the auxiliary! Here are some clues:

- One of the two infinitives is a modal verb. It's the modal verb that determines the auxiliary; and since modals need *haben*, it's *hätte*, not *wäre*.
- If we know which of the two infinitives replaces the past participle, then we know that that verb determines the auxiliary. In our sentence it is *sollen* which replaces *gesollt*. *Gesollt* needs *haben*, so it's *hätte*, not *wäre*.
- If unsure which of the two infinitives is the *Ersatzinfinitiv*, then take the last one. For example [this Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) says that the *Ersatzinfinitiv* takes the last position in a sentence. The last infinitive in our sentence is *sollen*. And since we know that *sollen* demands *haben* as an auxiliary, we are done.

[To answer the question in your title: No, even for *sein*-verbs the construction should be *hätte ... können*, not *wäre ... können*.]

Comment: Actually, the *Ersatzinfinitiv* is not restricted to longer constructions … I often find myself saying ‘Ich hätte sollen’ instead of ‘Ich hätte gesollt.’ My spontaneous reasoning says that I mearly left out what I should have done in there, but nonetheless the sentence is short.